# How to add new language to Languagetool?

Tags: libreoffice, spell-checking

I installed the [LanguageTool extension](https://languagetool.org/#libreoffice) to LibreOffice 5.1 and it worked perfectly, Now I want to add the Arabic language to it. I found [this page](https://github.com/linuxscout/languagetool) but I have no idea how I can add it to the extension I mentioned earlier.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Please also tell us, step by step, how you added the Language Tool extension to LibreOffice 5.1, and give us the name of the installation file you used. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. We don't have enough information to go on without it.

Comment: Note: https://forum.languagetool.org/search?q=arabic is another resource we will probably be consulting before long to help.